# Retrieve indeterminate state from checkbox Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I'm using Winforms and i am having trouble to retrieve indeterminate state from a checkbox.
it always return "unchecked"...

I use this code to set checkbox to indeterminate when the form load :

```
 checkBox.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate;
```

it works.

Then when i click on the checkbox,"CheckedChanged" event is firing and i want to do nothing if state is indeterminate.
But it return state "unchecked" while checkbox is displayed as "indeterminate"..

here is how i try to retrieve checkbox state :

```
CheckBox c = sender as CheckBox;
  if (c.CheckState == CheckState.Indeterminate)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nope");
        }
```

I did not find a solution except in WPF but i use Winforms..

Thanks for taking time to help me.

Comment: `ThreeState` property is set to `true`?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like the first click on a three-state checkbox that has the indeterminate value sets it to false.  If you want it to be set to true on first click, try using a two-state checkbox that defaults to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a `CheckBox` control with the `ThreeState` property set to `true`.
In `Form_Load` I've set the `CheckState` to `CheckState.Indeterminate` in the same way as you.
I've subscribed to the `CheckStateChanged` event on the CheckBox.

I can get the CheckState like this:

```
private void CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;

    switch (checkbox.CheckState)
    {
        case CheckState.Checked:
            MessageBox.Show("Checked");
            break;
        case CheckState.Unchecked:
            MessageBox.Show("Unchecked");
            break;
        case CheckState.Indeterminate:
            MessageBox.Show("Indeterminate");
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing");
            break;
    }
}
```

Obviously instead of MessageBox you would have your code.

Comment: yes, i was using CheckChanged instead of CheckStateChanged and threeState property wasn't set to true. i used your code and it worked ! thanks